# Unable to customize command prompt after installing oh-my-posh Theme on Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, centos-7, ps1

I'm using oh-my-posh theme to customize my terminal. I want to configure my command prompt adding more details but it doesn't work after installing the theme. Screenshot:

[image: Command Prompt]

Changing the command prompt only works when I remove the theme.

Comment: Hello, what exactly do you expect to happen there? Of course that's not going to work. Do you want to replace the whole prompt or just a part of it? Temporarily or permamently?

Comment: I'm really new to Linux and I tried to add more details to the command prompt using the prompt PS1="[insert codes here]." I don't understand why it doesn't work. Or I have to do it another way?

Comment: I've already described all the methods (temporary and permament) anyways (but please be more accurate with your questions next time), answer coming soon.

Comment: Did my answer help @diogenes31?

Answer (score 0):

### Why your attempt didn't work

Oh My Posh uses `PROMPT_COMMAND` env to hook into the shell and set its own `PS1`. It works this way:

1. You initialize [this](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/blob/6544815766966b185748d2411834f8f3bdc3ddcf/src/shell/scripts/omp.bash) `omp.bash` script with `eval "$(oh-my-posh init bash)"` or a similar command.
2. The script [adds](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/blob/6544815766966b185748d2411834f8f3bdc3ddcf/src/shell/scripts/omp.bash#L66) `_omp_hook` function to `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND="_omp_hook; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

3. That function [sets](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/blob/6544815766966b185748d2411834f8f3bdc3ddcf/src/shell/scripts/omp.bash#L61) `PS1` automatically before each line is printed, overriding anything you set manually:

```bash
PS1="..."
```

You can read more about `PROMPT_COMMAND` e.g [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html).

### Changing the prompt

Now if you want to:

- customize the prompt permamently, just [edit Oh My Posh's config](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/customize). Follow the documentation for any sort of configuration according to your needs.

---

- temporarily change it to something entirely different, you can:

1. Save current `PROMPT_COMMAND` in a variable, let's say:

```
OLD_PROMPT_COMMAND=PROMPT_COMMAND
```

2. Set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to a blank string. Or anything else if you want, just `_omp_hook` needs to be skipped. Setting `PS1` manually will start working again. E.g."

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="" && PS1="Temporary PS1 "
```

3. Restore `OLD_PROMPT_COMMAND` at a later point if needed:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=OLD_PROMPT_COMMAND
```

---

- temporarily add something to the prompt, use [text segment](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/text) with a template configured to show an environmental variable, e.g.

```
template: "{{ if .Env.YourVarName }}{{ .Env.YourVarName }}{{ end }}"
```

Then set the variable in shell:

```
export YourVarName=test
```